# Prevent notifications when loading fixtures

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some subscribers listening to Doctrine events and then sending email notifications on certain database changes.

I do not want these notifications to be sent when loading fixtures.

Is there a way to check if the `doctrine:fixtures:load` is running? Or maybe a way to pass an state from the fixtures to the subscriber?

Comment: Is `doctrine:fixtures:load running` on production?

Answer (score 0):

Add an environemnt with swiftmailer configured to not send emails.